# sys.login_token doesn't include particular windows groups while they can be listed by sys.database_principals

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, authentication, domain

When I query

```
SELECT principal_id, name, [type]
FROM sys.login_token
```

I found some local windows groups were not there.

However, when I check by

```
SELECT principal_id, name, [type]
FROM sys.database_principals
```

I can see those groups in the result.

I tried to remove then add back the associated users and logins as well as restart the SQL Server Service but didn't get lucky so far.

Not sure if I missed something obvious, any direction will be appreciated.

---

The problem appears to be more complicated than I thought.
The server is in domain B while the user account is under domain A.
Domain B has one-way trust to domain A so domain A user can login by their account to the server directly.

For policy or some technical problem, we can't add `DoamainA\UserAccount` to local group in the server straight; we have to contain `DoamainA\UserAccount` in a domain group of domain B then add this domain group to the local group on the server.

However, when I login by `DoamainA\UserAccount` in this condition, `sys.login_token` doesn't seems to recognize `DoamainA\UserAccount` as a member of local group.

I found this since when I create a new local account and add it to those disappeared local groups then login with this local account. Then I can see those disappeared groups be listed by `sys.login_token` without problem.

Therefore, did we mess up the one-way trust setting or it supposes to work in that way?
Is it normal that we can't add `DoamainA\UserAccount` directly when one-way trust? Or there should have some sort of um firewall or port setting we did wrong?

Comment: It will be good if you can write a test case to showcase this scenario. But my gut feeling is that sys.login_token is for server level logins, i.e. sys.server_principals, while sys.user_token should be for sys.database_principals. In another word, you are trying to find an apple out of a pile of oranges.

Comment: I can see those groups from `sys.server_principals` as well and I can't use `sys.user_token` since it will return only dbo if the user is a `sysadmin`

Comment: I will try to create test case but might not able to reproduce casue so far only two of my servers had this problem.